# What coin is this?

Tags: identification, numismatics

[image: square metallic blank with rounded corners showing apparently Egyptian symbols.]

[image: square metallic blank with rounded corners showing apparently Egyptian symbols.]
This is a coin I found in my grandmother's collection of old things. I would like to identify it. I'm not sure if its a replica or not.

Comment: Reverse image search does not give anything interesting, alas

Comment: Looks like tourist bait to me.

Comment: @kimchilover Thanks for the comment. I'm not sure what a tourist bait is

Comment: Why is the question closed? How Am I supposed to provide more information about it when I am genuinely asking for information?

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese kimchilover may well be right (just for tourists) but try adding some details about the coin's measurements and how heavy is it. Also, are there any possible clues from the collection in which you found it?

Comment: @LarsBosteen i will do so, Thanks. New question? or should I edit this? It was just a random collection of coins from different countries

Comment: Suggest you edit this one and let's see if we can get it reopened. Try to add as much info as you can.

Comment: You might also rotate the bottom image when you edit, so the figures are upright. The top image seems to be representative of a scene from [the tomb of Rekhmire](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bottom_musicians,_top_women%27s_salon,_Rekhmire_tt100_sh_421.jpg) showing a harpist and lute player. Did your grandmother  ever travel to Egypt, or have special interest in ancient musical instruments?

Comment: @justCal  Good spotting re Rekhmire.  So the "coin" is no older than the modern publication of TT100's images, that is certainly not before 1832. And probably a century younger.